# jQuery buttonset: intercept clicks so that buttons don't change state

Tags: jquery-ui, events, button

I am using jQuery UI buttonset for an on/off pair of buttons, mainly because of the nice styling you get with it. I want to handle clicks so that when you click one of the two buttons you get a dialog where you can make some more choices, and after that the page reloads with the buttons in their new state (if the state was changed, which may not be the case).

The problem is that the button that you click gets styled as selected before any click handlers are called, it seems. I don't want the selection to change, I want to do that manually.

It seems that the click event is bound to the label that jQuery UI creates, and I'm struggling a bit with unbinding it. I guess I'm also asking if there is some other way to get the style without the function... since buttonset doesn't offer any event handlers I need to catch the click events myself anyway.

The solution I'm thinking of right now is simply copying the html that buttonset generates into my code, keep the css and remove the buttonset call. I thought it might worth it to check on StackOverflow before giving up though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since jQuery UI doesn't trigger any events that run before for the actual selection is made the workarounds to accomplish this are going to be relatively hacky.  The best idea I could come up with is to programmatically remember the previously selected option and then attach a `click` handler that determines whether you should revert jQuery UI's selection of the new button or not.

```
$('#parent_container').buttonset();
var selectedButton = $('#parent_container :checked');
$('.ui-button').on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //Insert your actual check here.
        if (true) {
            selectedButton.attr('checked', true);
            $('#radio').buttonset('refresh');
        } else {
            selectedButton = $('#parent_container :checked');
        }
    }, 1);
});​
```

The `setTimeout` is necessary to ensure that this runs after jQuery UI's click handler.  Since you're showing a dialog you might need to alter this to instantly revert the selection, but remember what the user attempted to select for future use.

I have an example of always refusing the user's selection here - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/s6XTu/14/

Obviously this is not an ideal approach but it does work.  jQuery UI should really add support  for selection events; I'll try to get around to filing a ticket for this.  The button plugin is due for some updates in 1.11 - http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138038/Roadmap.

Comment: I went with this solution, thanks. It seems to be the least awkward solution. Once my dialog has been shown I run something like: $("#" + buttonId).attr("checked", "checked"); $("#" + buttonId).button("refresh"); - another awkward thing about buttonset is that there's no utility method for manually changing the state for both the input tag and the buttonset visual element in one call.